# Why Can't I access my website ,even if 80 port of my ecs server is open?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw

os system of ecs server :ubuntu.
os of my computer:win10.
I deployed my web project to my ecs server. I could access my project online until I installed the ufw on my ecs server. I cofigured the firewall using ufw command and the configuration showed as below.

```
  root@....:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
23                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
23 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When i visited my project using my win10 computer,it showed  "I can't access this website".Then I click the "windowns network diagnosis".It said"The remote computer is not accepting connections on port 80, either due to firewall or security policy settings, or because the service may be temporarily unavailable. Windows can't find any problems with the computer's firewall."
But  the 80 port is open!So ,Where is the problem?
Thank you for your suggestions.I will wait online.

Comment: If you disable `ufw` can you then access the website?

Comment: Did you also install and configure a web-server, like Apache or Nginx, correctly ?

Comment: I disabled ufw，but I couldn't visit it either.

Comment: I could access the index page of my project before I  installed ufw.So I think the nginx configuration is right

Comment: If you disabled ufw and you can't reach it, then ufw is not the problem.

Comment: The network diagnose says："The remote machine is not accepting connections on port 80, either because of firewall or security policy Settings, or because the service may be temporarily unavailable. Windows found nothing wrong with the computer's firewall."   So any other suggestions?

Comment: are you using amazon ec? I think you need to configure firewall from aws, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Comment: I use AliYun ecs in China